# Why my SerialPorts.GetPortNames() gets exception error 'no data is available' when there was data?

Tags: c#, .net, exe

this is my code

```
private void updatePorts()
        {
            List<string> Pnames = ComPortNames("0403", "6015");  //"0403", "6015" 
            isConnected = new bool[100];
           Debug.WriteLine("List of portnames: " + String.Join(",", Pnames));
            // For all the poches that are connected
            // no.1 Debug.WriteLine("List of getportname: " + String.Join(",", SerialPort.GetPortNames()));
        //no.2    
foreach (String s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
               // Debug.WriteLine("amport: " + s);
                for (int i = 0; i < Pnames.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (s == Pnames[i])
                    {
                        int unpluggedPortNum = unpluggedPort(s); // Checked if it is unplugged, -1 if not
                        int portNum = existingPort(s); // Check if it is already and exisitng one, -1 if not

                        if (unpluggedPortNum != -1) //If it was an unplugged port, restart the connection and bring over the data (same id)
                        {
                            AMPports[unpluggedPortNum] = new SerialPort();
                            AMPports[unpluggedPortNum].PortName = s;
.
.
.
```

I received data in the line with comment '//no.1' but when it reached to code under comment '//no.2', 'SerialPort.GetPortNames()', there was an exception error that said that there was no data available. Thing is there are data (comports) connected.

This error occur when i keep testing to plug in and out different com. Is there any way to handle this exception? to bypass this using try catch? or to handle if there is exception then display error to user?

i am new to this C# and .NET and EXE so would really appreciate this help! thank you!

Update:

i get this error msg in my output

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Comment: A port is probably being closed in the for loop so you are getting the error after looping inside the for loop (not the first time you enter the for loop).

Comment: ohh.. so is it not possible to loop it and plug in plug out com ? like this error will be at high risk to occur?

Comment: You cannot modify the loop array inside the for loop.